# Implementing both DataItem.DataListener interface and WearableListenerService

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api, moto-360

In Android Wear application i've implemented  *DataItem.DataListener* interface for an Activity. Since i already created *WearableListenerService* for some other usages. Now the situation is when i want *onDatachanged()* in **MyActivity**  it will execute *onDatachanged()* of **WearablelistenerService**. Also viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use the path (`event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();`) to define the recipient or the purpose of the respective data map. Every listener should evaluate certain paths only to avoid confusions.